# Is this if condition equivalent to testing the existence of a variable?

Tags: bash

I'm digging around in some the system files on my Mac. In `/etc/profile` I've found the following excerpt:

```
 if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
 fi
```

I've tried `echo "${x-no}"` for various choices of `x` and it seems like it's printing the value of `x` whenever `x` exists (i.e. has been set), and `no` otherwise.

Which leads me to wonder: Is this condition simply testing whether the variable `x` has been set?

Further questions: What exactly does `-` do? Is there a better way to test whether a variable has been set?

Comment: See "Parameter Expansion" in `man bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `${BASH-no}` is documented in [§2.6.2, Parameter Expansion, of the Single Unix Specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> ${*parameter*:-**[***word***]**}
>
> **Use Default Values.** If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* (or an empty string if word is omitted) shall be substituted; otherwise, the value of parameter shall be substituted.

The meaning when the colon is omitted (as in your example) is described slightly later:

> In the parameter expansions shown previously, use of the  in the format shall result in a test for a parameter that is unset or null; omission of the  shall result in a test for a parameter that is only unset.

Then there is a table, which may be easier to understand. Here are the relevant rows:

|  | *parameter* Set and Not Null | *parameter* Set but Null | *parameter* Unset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **${***parameter***:-***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | substitute *word* | substitute *word* |
| **${***parameter***-***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | substitute null | substitute *word* |

Here is a reliable, portable way to check whether a variable is not set at all. Note that I am using a `+` modifier instead of a `-` modifier in the parameter expansion:

```
if [ "${BASH+set}" = "" ]; then
    echo 'BASH not set at all'
else
    echo 'BASH is set, perhaps to the empty string'
fi
```

The expansion of `"${BASH+set}"` can only be `""` if `BASH` is entirely unset. If `BASH` is set, even to the empty string, then `"${BASH+set}"` expands to `"set"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this condition simply testing whether the variable x has been set?

Yes, though it gets confused in the unlikely event that `BASH=no`.

> What exactly does - do?

Here's `man bash`:

```
[...] Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is  un‐set.

   ${parameter:-word}
         Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null (see above),
         the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the
         value of parameter is substituted.
```

> Is there a better way to test whether a variable has been set?

Yes: `[ -v BASH ]`. However, this is bash specific, so it defeats the purpose of checking if the current shell is bash before doing bash specific operations.